# How to call asynchronous function each time for each object in array param

Tags: node.js, asynchronous

I have a asynchronous function, say 
getConfigPricingFromResourceQuery(element, function(configPricingFromResourceQuery){

//do stuff
});

Im sending the each value of the elements[] array to this asynchronous function.But this function is called single time even-though the array holds more than one value. More clearly, this function is called single time sending all the values together to this function. But this is not expected here because i need to do stuffs for each and every value of the array param.

Complete code is given below:

Function Defintion :

function getConfigPricingFromResourceQuery(elements, callback) {

```
            var configJson = {};

            // configJson contains parameters required for resourceservice validate api.
            var configJson = elements.parameters;

            trace.info(elements.uri);

            configJson.instanceTypeUri = elements.uri;

            jsonObject = JSON.stringify(configJson);

                // prepare the header
            var postheaders = {
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Length' : Buffer.byteLength(jsonObject, 'utf8')
            };

            // the post options
            var optionspost = {
            host :  '192.168.3.243',
            port :  5902,
            path :  '/apiv1.0/resourceQuery/validate',
            method : 'POST',
            headers : postheaders
            };

            // do the POST call to resource service
            var reqPost = http.get(optionspost, function(response) {
                trace.log("statusCode: ", response.statusCode);

                response.on('data', function(d) {
                    trace.info('POST result:\n');
                    process.stdout.write(d);
                    configPricing += d;
                    trace.info(configPricing);
                    trace.info('POST completed');
                    return callback(JSON.parse(configPricing));
                });
            }); 
            // write the json data
            reqPost.write(jsonObject);
            //reqPost.end();
            reqPost.on('error', function(e) {
                console.error(e);
            });

        //return callback(configPricing);
    };
```

call this function:

getConfigPricingFromResourceQuery(elements, function(configPricingFromResourceQuery){
                trace.info('########################################');
                var metadataConfigJsonArray = [];
                var metadataConfigJson = {

```
                    chargeAmount: Math.round(configPricingFromResourceQuery.totalUnitPrice * 100)/100,
                    chargeamountUnit: configPricingFromResourceQuery.ChargeAmountUnit,
                    currencyCode: configPricingFromResourceQuery.CurrencyCode
                }
            metadataConfigJsonArray.push(metadataConfigJson);
            if(elements.metadata) { }
            else
            {
                elements.metadata={};
            }

            metadataModified = elements.metadata;

            // TODO : Remove this hard-coding
            elementlevelpricingSummary.Name = 'Hardware';

            if(configPricingFromResourceQuery.totalUnitPrice)
            {
                var chargeAmount = configPricingFromResourceQuery.totalUnitPrice;

                elementlevelpricingSummary.chargeAmount = Math.round(chargeAmount * 100)/100;
            }
            if(configPricingFromResourceQuery.ChargeAmountUnit)
            {
                var chargeAmountUnit = configPricingFromResourceQuery.ChargeAmountUnit;

                elementlevelpricingSummary.chargeAmountUnit = configPricingFromResourceQuery.ChargeAmountUnit;
            }
            if(configPricingFromResourceQuery.CurrencyCode)
            {
                var currencyCode = configPricingFromResourceQuery.CurrencyCode;

                elementlevelpricingSummary.currencyCode = configPricingFromResourceQuery.CurrencyCode;
            }   

            metadataModified.pricingSummary = metadataConfigJsonArray;

            configurableElementarray.push(elementlevelpricingSummary);

            // delete original metadata from workload json (to be replaced by metadata containing pricing summary)
            delete elementinfo.metadata;

            elementinfo.metadata = metadataModified;

            elementArray.push(elementinfo);

            // global workloadinfo variable is appended with array of elements with its pricing summary within metadata of respective elements
            workloadinfo.elements = elementArray;

            return callback(null, workloadinfo);
            });
```

Comment: Can you format your code better?

Answer (score 0):

It's called once because you only called it once, passing in the whole array:

```
getConfigPricingFromResourceQuery(elements, function(result){ 
    // Your lovely callback
})
```

If you want to get the config price for each object in the elements array then you have to call it for each of them

```
elements.forEach(function (e) {
    getConfigPricingFromResourceQuery(e, function (result) {
        // handle the result
    }
})
```

I'd also encourage that you use Node style callbacks `function (err, value) {}` which allows you to pass the errors through the callbacks.

If you want to turn your array of elements into an array of results then you need to be a bit more clever about it, and you should probably use a module to do that for you. Look on npm for a parallel array module such as [continuable-para](https://npmjs.org/package/continuable-para)

```
var para = require("continuable-para")

para(elements.map(function () {
    return getConfigPricingFromResourceQuery.bind(null, e)
}), function (err, pricesArray) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err)
    }

    pricesArray.forEach(function (price) { /* handle the price */ })
})
```